# Hierarchical logging with console.log

Tags: reactjs, logging

This is my first React.js project and I added logging via npm debug following this [tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/step-up-your-console-messaging-game-in-your-react-app-42eee17659ec).

My goal is have a human readable log of everything the program is doing, so that when I hit a bug, it's quick to diagnose. The app has a lot of tree logic that's determined by content in a CMS (the logic is also in the CMS), so the debugging needs to be clear as the content changes and gets more complicated.

My problem is that after logging everything, the stream is too flat. It's hard to know when big tasks are done (and which are the small tasks that need to be done in order for the big task to be done). My log looks like this right now:

[My logging output right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpuwD.png)

Is there another logging system I should use? Or is there some kind of DevOps or Analytics tool out there that will automatically provide some better organization of my logs depending on whether or not they are nested functions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by using `console.group` and `console.groupEnd();` to start and end groups in the console. I ended up following the tutorial [here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/advanced-javascript-logging-using-console-group).

I now have this component:

```
const COLOURS = {
  trace: '#aaa',
  info: 'blue',
  warn: 'pink',
  error: 'red'
};

class Log {
  generateMessage(level, message, source, group) {
    var textColor = COLOURS[level];

    if(!group){
      if(typeof message === "object"){
        console.log("This is an object")
      } else {
        console.log("%c"+source+"  ||  %c"+message, "color:#000;", "color:"+textColor+";")
      }

    } else if(group === "start") {
      console.group("%c"+source+"  ||  %c"+message, "color:#000;", "color:"+textColor+";")
    } else if(group === "end"){
      console.groupEnd();
    }

  }

  trace(message, source, group) {
    return this.generateMessage('trace', message, source, group);
  }

  info(message, source, group) {
    return this.generateMessage('info', message, source, group);
  }

  warn(message, source, group) {
    return this.generateMessage('warn', message, source, group);
  }

  error(message, source, group) {
    return this.generateMessage('error', message, source, group);
  }
}

export default new Log();
```

and then if I want to start a new grouping of a log, I can use (for example):

`Log.trace("Lesson data successful retrieved from Contentful.", "Lesson.js", "start")`

and if I want to end the group, I can use:

`Log.trace(null,null,"end")`

This results in my console now looking like this: [my console now with grouped messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNlpj.png)